# How to filter data according to the rule: if this value exists then filter for it, if not -> filter for another one

Tags: r, dplyr

```
id <-c ("A1", "A2", "A3", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A6", "A7")
v <-c ("V6", "V6", "V6", "VDS", "V6", "V6", "V6", "VDS", "V6")
s <- c("nr", "r", "nr", "nr", "r", "r", "nr", "r", "nr")
i <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")
data <- data.frame(id,v,s,i)
```

My data looks like that after filtering, selection etc. Now I need to do one more filtering, which I don't know how to do actually. The rule is "if `VDS` exist in column v then take rows for this value, if not take values for `V6`. Mainly it is that the values in the id column cannot repeat, and for the same id sometimes both `VDS` and `V6` occur. Is anyone able to help me?

Answer (score 2):

Couple of options -

1. Using `arrange` and `distinct`.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  arrange(id, desc(v)) %>%
  distinct(id, .keep_all = TRUE)

#  id   v  s i
#1 A1  V6 nr A
#2 A2  V6  r B
#3 A3 VDS nr D
#4 A4  V6  r E
#5 A5  V6  r F
#6 A6 VDS  r H
#7 A7  V6 nr I
```

2. Explicitly mention the condition in `filter`.

```
data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(if(any(v == 'VDS')) v == 'VDS' else v == 'V6')
```

Comment: The first option seems to work fine, although I don't quite understand where he knows to first check if VDS exists and if not to take the V6. How does it know that it should remove V6 if there is both VDS AND V6 in the id. The second option on the other hand changes all values to V6.

Comment: The 1st option works correctly because `'VDS' > 'V6'` so when we `arrange` it using `desc(v)` it arranges the `'VDS'` value first (if present) and then `'V6'` value. `distinct` takes 1st row for each `ID`.  I am not sure why the second option doesn't work since it works for me on the sample data and produces the same output as 1st option. Do you have `NA` values in `v` column ? In that case change `==` to `%in%`.